Even though I got full score in mail-tester, gmail still gives an error of IP address not being authorized when using sendmail
I'm using sendmail and I passed the DMARC, SPF and DKIM
but when I send an email to example@gmail.com, I get this below error:
50-5.7.1 The IP you're using to send mail is not
550-5.7.1 authorized to send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP
550-5.7.1 relay at your service provider instead. For more information, go to
550 5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NotAuthorizedError  - gsmtp
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable

Can I fix this without using external SMTP relay service?

Here you go, follow this advice to see if anything there helps: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10336?visit_id=638495915986371668-1377298714&p=NotAuthorizedError&rd=1. It seems like the reputation of whatever public IP you are sending from, it does not like that IP and has a bad reputation perhaps.

This appears to be a Google policy. As stated on the page provided in the failure response, Google is following a policy based on what they think is the policy of the IP address owner. It may be possible that this IP address owner does not have the policy Google thinks it has, in which case the IP address owner can try contacting Google.

I would checkout Google Postmaster tools. Postmaster Tools is a service that allows website and email senders to engage with Google on deliverability issues. It may save you a lot of time.

when I opened it, it shows that I'm compliant with all the requirements
